# EKS - Kubernetes - nginx-ingress-controller-default-ingress-controller - open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, k8s-serviceaccount

we have an EKS cluster on 1.21.

There is an nginx-ingress-controller-default-ingress-controller deployed with a Classic Load Balancer.

Suddenly, its pods are crashing with following errors.

```
I0815 04:40:04.970835       8 flags.go:204] Watching for Ingress class: nginx
W0815 04:40:04.980149       8 flags.go:249] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W0815 04:40:04.980218       8 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
W0815 04:40:04.980255       8 client_config.go:548] error creating inClusterConfig, falling back to default config: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
F0815 04:40:04.980417       8 main.go:272] Error while initiating a connection to the Kubernetes API server. This could mean the cluster is misconfigured (e.g. it has invalid API server certificates or Service Accounts configuration). Reason: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
```

Below are the securityContext and VolumeMount of the pod.

```
 securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      capabilities:
        add:
        - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        drop:
        - ALL
      runAsUser: 101
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-k7n9n
      readOnly: true
```

I tried to change runAsUser : 0, but it throws back with message the pods ".." is invalid.

Can you please give me some directions on what can be wrong here and any possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `fsGroup`. This will make serviceaccount directory readable by non-root user:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534
```

Comment: Hello Vsaili, I added in pod yaml, but it throws error. # pods "nginx-ingress-controller-default-ingress-controller-79b9c4gb6kx" was not valid:
# * <nil>: Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].securityContext): unknown field "fsGroup" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecurityContext
# I added under spec->containers->securityContext after runAsUser: 101. Pardon me if I am making changes at wrong place, since I am still learning this.

Comment: Also, I tried to add under spec->securityContext in next attemp, but it throws validation error. Currently it is set as securityContext: {}

Comment: You need to add `fsGroup` under `spec.template.spec.securityContext`

Answer (score 1):

Go to your nginx controller **DaemonSet** and include the `fsGroup` with value `65534` to help you run the container for non-root user.

When you run containers with non-root users (a security best practice), you might encounter permission issues when writing to volume-mounted directories, especially if the containerized application expects to write files with specific permissions. Setting `fsGroup: 65534` can help prevent permission issues by ensuring that the files created in the volume are not owned by any privileged group.

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534
```